# Three versions of libreoffice?

Tags: apt, package-management, libreoffice

I seem to have three versions of LibreOffice installed.  I used the database occasionally for mail merges, so I suspect the 7.0 version is the one I want to keep.  Is there a short `apt-get` command that will remove the other two without breaking anything?

```
$ libreoffice  [\t for autocomplete]
libreoffice     libreoffice6.4  libreoffice7.0  
`
$ which libreoffice
/usr/bin/libreoffice

$ ls -las /usr/bin/libreoffice
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Nov  2 08:44 /usr/bin/libreoffice -> ../lib/libreoffice/program/soffice

$ which libreoffice7.0
/usr/local/bin/libreoffice7.0

$ ls -las /usr/local/bin/libreoffice7.0
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Sep 30 21:29 /usr/local/bin/libreoffice7.0 -> /opt/libreoffice7.0/program/soffice

$ which libreoffice6.4
/usr/local/bin/libreoffice6.4

$ ls -las /usr/local/bin/libreoffice6.4 
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 May 13  2020 /usr/local/bin/libreoffice6.4 -> /opt/libreoffice6.4/program/soffice
```

Edit: I'm on Ubuntu Studio v 20.10

```
$  dpkg -l | grep libreoffice
ii  liblibreoffice-java                                         1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- Java library
ii  liblibreofficekitgtk                                        1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        GTK3 widget wrapping LibreOffice functionality
ii  libobasis6.4-libreofficekit-data                            6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Libreofficekit data files for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libobasis7.0-libreofficekit-data                            7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Libreofficekit data files for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice-base                                            1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- database
ii  libreoffice-base-core                                       1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- shared library
ii  libreoffice-base-drivers                                    1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        Database connectivity drivers for LibreOffice
ii  libreoffice-calc                                            1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- spreadsheet
ii  libreoffice-common                                          1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- arch-independent files
ii  libreoffice-core                                            1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- arch-dependent files
ii  libreoffice-draw                                            1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- drawing
ii  libreoffice-gnome                                           1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- GNOME integration
ii  libreoffice-gtk                                             1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          transitional package for LibreOffice gtk2 backend
ii  libreoffice-gtk2                                            1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          transitional package for LibreOffice gtk2 backend
ii  libreoffice-gtk3                                            1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- GTK+ 3 integration
ii  libreoffice-help-common                                     1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- common files for LibreOffice help
ii  libreoffice-help-en-gb                                      1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- English_british help
ii  libreoffice-help-en-us                                      1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- English_american help
ii  libreoffice-impress                                         1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- presentation
ii  libreoffice-java-common                                     1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- arch-independent Java support files
ii  libreoffice-kf5                                             1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- KDE Frameworks 5 integration
ii  libreoffice-l10n-en-gb                                      1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- English_british language package
ii  libreoffice-l10n-en-za                                      1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- English_southafrican language package
ii  libreoffice-math                                            1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- equation editor
ii  libreoffice-plasma                                          1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- some Plasma integration
ii  libreoffice-qt5                                             1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- Qt 5 integration
ii  libreoffice-script-provider-python                          1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          Python script support provider for LibreOffice scripting framework
ii  libreoffice-sdbc-firebird                                   1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        Firebird SDBC driver for LibreOffice
ii  libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb                                     1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        HSQLDB SDBC driver for LibreOffice
ii  libreoffice-style-breeze                                    1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- Breeze symbol style
ii  libreoffice-style-colibre                                   1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- colibre symbol style
ii  libreoffice-style-elementary                                1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- Elementary symbol style
ii  libreoffice-style-galaxy                                    1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          transitional package for Galaxy symbol style
ii  libreoffice-style-tango                                     1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          transitional package for Tango symbol style
ii  libreoffice-style-yaru                                      1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          office productivity suite -- Yaru symbol style
ii  libreoffice-writer                                          1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- word processor
ii  libreoffice6.4                                              6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Brand module for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-base                                         6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Base brand module for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-calc                                         6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Calc brand module for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-debian-menus                                 6.4.4-2                                     all          LibreOffice 6.4 desktop integration
ii  libreoffice6.4-dict-en                                      6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        En dictionary for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-dict-es                                      6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Es dictionary for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-dict-fr                                      6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Fr dictionary for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-draw                                         6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Draw brand module for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-en-us                                        6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Brand language module for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-impress                                      6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Impress brand module for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-math                                         6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Math brand module for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-ure                                          6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        UNO Runtime Environment .4.2
ii  libreoffice6.4-writer                                       6.4.4.2-2                                   amd64        Writer brand module for LibreOffice 6.4 .4.2
ii  libreoffice7.0                                              7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Brand module for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-base                                         7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Base brand module for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-calc                                         7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Calc brand module for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-debian-menus                                 7.0.2-2                                     all          LibreOffice 7.0 desktop integration
ii  libreoffice7.0-dict-en                                      7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        En dictionary for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-dict-es                                      7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Es dictionary for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-dict-fr                                      7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Fr dictionary for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-draw                                         7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Draw brand module for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-en-us                                        7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Brand language module for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-impress                                      7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Impress brand module for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-math                                         7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Math brand module for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-ure                                          7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        UNO Runtime Environment .2.2
ii  libreoffice7.0-writer                                       7.0.2.2-2                                   amd64        Writer brand module for LibreOffice 7.0 .2.2
ii  libreofficekit-data                                         1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1                    all          common data for LOKDocView
```

Comment: It depends on how you installed LO. Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep libreoffice` command.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that one of the versions I got from doing an apt-get on the command line and then subsequent versions I think I added the Document Foundation's PPA and then did another apt-get.  I incorrectly assumed that these upgrades would remove older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have just one version of libreoffice and it is the latest one.

What I did:

```
% sudo apt-get remove libreoffice6.4
% sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
% sudo apt-get update
% sudo apt-get upgrade
% sudo apt-get remove libreoffice7.0
```

I've still got libreoffice-base installed and `libreoffice --help` shows a version over 7, so this is a success.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to remove the LibreOffice that came with the distro. It can break other things that depend on it.

But you can try to run

```
sudo apt remove libreoffice6.4 
sudo apt autoremove
```

But be very carefull when you see the list of packages to be removed. It can completely break your system.

Comment: Is there anything that depends on libreoffice?

Comment: There maybe a lot including `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: I'm not sure that Ubuntu Studio ships with libre office. It didn't used to.